# Hiding button inside div in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

Hi we developing web application using jquery mobile and mvc. In one criteria i need to hide button inside div when page loads. In few criteria i need to show button.

**view**

```
<div id="ContentSerialNumberSearch">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSerialScac" name="btnDPSearch"  data-theme="d" value="@Resources.ViewScac" data-ajax="false"/>
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSerialLane" name="btnDPSearch"  data-theme="d" value="@Resources.ViewLane" data-ajax="false"/>
                </div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
       $('#btnSerialScac').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
       $('#btnSerialLane').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
   });
```

The above code works great. But i used pageinit event so each time the function execute even if i visit other pages. It will lead to performance issue. so i tried below code.

**script**

```
 $( document ).on( "pagecontainershow",'#ContentSerialNumberSearch', function ( event, ui ) {
       $('#btnSerialScac').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
       $('#btnSerialLane').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
   });
```

so i thought the above script will be execute only when the particular div is loaded in dom. But the button inside DOM is not hiding. I tried pageshow,mobileinit event but no use. Please guide me.

Comment: _Please_ read the tag excerpts before adding just any tag... [jq] is _not_ for jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but to use the pagecontainer widget event for show, you would do it like this:

```
$("body").on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
       $('#btnSerialScac').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
       $('#btnSerialLane').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
});
```

or instead of body, ":mobile-pagecontainer"

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
       $('#btnSerialScac').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
       $('#btnSerialLane').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/JLV29/)**

Using pagecontainershow will hide the buttons everytime you navigate between pages.

Comment: the pagecontainershow works fine. but its like pageinit event only. the function executing each time when page loads even other pages. i need to avoid it. only in particular page the function should call.

Comment: @Ryder, http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show, you can check ui.toPage to see which page is about to show and only hide the buttons if that page is being visited. If you only want the event to run once when page is created, use $(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageid", function(){}); where pageid is the id assigned to the data-role="page" div.